# Set nginx to answer for all domains

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have this setup with apache but want to move over to nginx. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

In apache I had it as `ServerAlias *`

What would be the nginx equivalent?

I've tried `server_name www.example.net default_server;` and `server_name _;` but that doesn't seem to work. I just keep getting a 404 every time I visit any host but `www.example.com`.

**Update**
It seems that serving static files is not a problem. So it is pointing correctly but PHP files are giving me a 404 error (using php-fpm). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the user for the php-fpm pool have the right permissions to read the PHP files in the directory? i.e. if Nginx is running as www-data:www-data (as mine does) but your php-fpm pool is running as "user:user", then does the "user" account have the right permissions on the webroot to be able to open the PHP files?

Comment: Yes it does. Using www.example.com/index.php I can see what I'm supposed to be seeing. When I try to access it using foo.example.com/index.php I get a 404 error.

Comment: Sounds like checking the php-fpm and/or nginx logs is the only way forward then, I haven't used your setup specifically but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I see this error in the nginx error log: 2012/05/24 08:06:04 [error] 32072#0: *17 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 96.48.131.149, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "foo.example.com"
2012/05/24 08:06:04 [error] 32072#0: *17 open() "/home/example/frontend/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 96.48.131.149, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "foo.example.com"  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok it seems like the problem is with my php script itself. However I am unable to tell what the error is exactly.

Comment: Found the issue instead of giving a 500 error it was showing a 404.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently an invalid `server_name` like `_` should serve as a [catch all virtual host](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample).